# How do I avoid HWE kernel upgrades in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I currently have problems with HWE kernel support in 14.04LTS, and I want to head them off when I upgrade to 16.04LTS.

According to [this page](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3098865/linux/ubuntu-16-04-1-is-out-with-improvements-to-software-installation-and-low-graphics-mode.html), I'll upgrade to 16.04 point releases automatically through the usual `apt-get update/upgrade' procedure.  This will include HWE stack updates that (at least in 14.04) automatically update the kernel to non-LTS kernel versions.

I don't want these non-LTS kernel versions.  How can I upgrade 14.04 to 16.04.1 without risking installing a non-LTS kernel once 16.04.2 comes around?

Comment: Show the output of `linux-version list`